# routing in angular 4 not working for child component

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular4-router

I am implementing `routing` in my `angular` for app. I have created a **moviecomponent**, **editmoviecomponent**.

The **editmoviecomponent** is nested within **moviecomponent** as seen in the folder structure below.

[image]

The moviecomponent.html has a grid with a column that contains the routerlink pointing to editmoviecomponent. I can see the link which seems correct in the browser address bar but for some reason the endmoviecomponent.html doesnt get rendered. Instead the NotFound page gets rendered which is also defined in the route. It seems like the route definition in the approuting.module isnt correct.

**movie.component.html**

```
<kendo-grid-column title="Edit" headerClass="kendoGridHeader" class="kendoGridControlCell">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
       <span data-title="Edit" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleEdit">
         <a [routerLink]="['./edit', dataItem.movieId]" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </span>
     </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

**movie.component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from './movie.service';
import {IMovie} from './movie.interface';
import { GridDataResult, PageChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from '../shared/mrdb.global.constants';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css'],
  providers:[MovieService]
})
```

**editmovie.component.html**

```
<p>
  editmovie works!
</p>
```

**editmovie.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editmovie',
   moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './editmovie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editmovie.component.css']
})
export class EditmovieComponent implements OnInit {

public selectMovieId: number = 0;
public sub : any;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectMovieId = + params['id']; // (+) converts string to number
    }) 
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**approuting.module**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie/movie.component';
import {HomeComponent}  from '../app/home/home.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';

import {NewmovieComponent} from './movie/new/newmovie.component';
import {EditmovieComponent} from './movie/edit/editmovie.component';
import {ViewmovieComponent} from './movie/view/viewmovie.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent},
{path : 'new' , component : NewmovieComponent },
{path : 'edit/:id' , component : EditmovieComponent },
{path : 'view/:id' , component : ViewmovieComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{path : '', component : HomeComponent},
{path: '**', component : NotFoundComponent}

];

@NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
     exports: [RouterModule]

})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Could somebody tell me what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
{path : 'movie/edit/:id' , component : EditmovieComponent }
```

or :

```
 {
    path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent , children : [
        {path : 'edit/:id' , component : EditmovieComponent }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: The first does render me a page other than notfound page though I doubt its editmodule.html page as I cant see the contents of the page rendered. There is no error in the console window either. The children route in the second option doesnt work at all and throws error in the console window

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        EditmovieComponent
    ],
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
     exports: [RouterModule]

})
```

you need to import the component parent module or declare component in routing module

Answer (score 0):

why you are using the relative path here './edit' it should be absolute:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['edit', dataItem.movieId]" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

if you want to use child routes you have to add

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

inside your movie.component.html

```
{
path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent , children : [
    {path : 'edit/:id' , component : EditmovieComponent }
]}
```

and in movie component

```
  <kendo-grid-column title="Edit" headerClass="kendoGridHeader" class="kendoGridControlCell">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
     <span data-title="Edit" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleEdit">
       <a [routerLink]="['./edit', dataItem.movieId]" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </span>
  </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```